# Pass a value to an inFrame

Tags: php, forms, iframe, variables

This probably an easy thing to do but for some reason I can't get a handle on it.

I have a simple form that allows people to select one if three items for sale. When they chose their item I need to pass that variable into an iFrame with a third party checkout page to safely process their cc transaction.

How would I do this?

Cheers-

Answer (score 2):

The simplest, even JavaScript-less way to do this is giving the iframe a `name` attribute:

```
<iframe name="order_confirmation" id="order_confirmation" src="">
```

(I'm not 100% sure right now whether it's also `id` or just `name` you can use, I'm pretty sure it's `name`)

and then using that name as the `target` in the form:

```
<form action='whatever' target='order_confirmation' ....>
```

the form will then be submitted into the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

On the URL is the easiest

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to put it on the url.  For instance if they select item1 then: http://checkout.com?ID=Item1.